# Execute python file from another python script, failed if python file has nested function

Tags: python, dynamic, hyperlink

I'm creating a python script to do I2C read and write. The script also handles test scripts (also in python) to send hardware.
The test scripts previously are sent through GUI, but my script by-passes GUI usage and talks to I2C driver directly.
If the test scripts are flat, no problem. However, if there's nested function or global variable, there's error:

```
def main():
    board=usb2any()
    board.ReadI2C(0x58,0x0)
    board.WriteI2C(0x58,0xBC,0x40)
    execfile(f1)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The test code "f1",  if it only contains codes like below, it runs fine

```
board.ReadI2C(0x58,0x2)
board.WriteI2C(0x58,0x20,0x10)
```

however if it looks like this:
test script example 1

```
V1=0
def fun1():
    if V1==1: # error here saying global variable V1 not defined
```

Another example of failed case:
test script example 2

```
ff(0x10,0x9)
def ff(v1,v2):
    fun2(v1)   #Error here saying fun2 not defined
```

def fun2(vv):
        vv=0

Any idea how to solve this? prefer not touching test scripts because those have been used with GUI.

Comment: when you create `def fun1()` with `V1` declared above it, you're not passing V1 into the function, so how would `fun1()` know what `V1` is? You have to pass a parameter into the function such as `def fun1(V1):` then you can use the variable within the local function.

Answer (score 0):

Example 2 doesn't work because you are calling the function before declaring it. Try this instead:

```
def ff(v1,v2): 
    fun2(v1) 
ff(0x10,0x9)
```

Answer (score 0):

Example 2 needs some rearranging so you  define the functions before calling them.  You might want to make a class if you're calling lots of functions from each other.

```
def fun2(vv): 
    vv=0

def ff(v1,v2): 
    fun2(v1)
```

`

Comment: also tried using file_globals = runpy.run_path(file_name), error occurs when board.WriteI2C is called saying board is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what's working and what's not:
For test script example 1, need to add global in test script
    global V1
    V1=0
    def fun1():
        if V1==1: #now there's no error

Another example of failed case:
test script example 2, which shifting the sequence, still failed

```
def fun2(x):
    x = 0

def ff(vv):
    fun2(vv)
ff(2) #when calling ff, error saying no fun2 defined
```

Printout info:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "c:\Users\a0272122\Documents\Python Scripts\I2C_USB2Any\i2c_wr.py", line 68, in 
    main()

File "c:\Users\a0272122\Documents\Python Scripts\I2C_USB2Any\i2c_wr.py", line 42, in main
    execfile(file_name)

File "pattern_test.py", line 122, in 
    **apb_read_modifywrite**(0x1A4, 0x000000E0, 0x00000020)

File "pattern_test.py", line 113, in apb_read_modifywrite
    read_data = **apb_read_reg**(addr16b)

NameError: global name 'apb_read_reg' is not defined